# HTML, CSS: Styling a link and making the whole div link

Tags: html, css

I want to have a whole box (delimited by a < div >) containing a text act as a link but I also want the text in that link to be styled. I can't seem to get both:

(1)

HTML

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('category')"><div class="categoryName">Test</div></a>
```

CSS

```css
.categoryName {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.categoryName a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In this case my whole box (the bordered < div >) acts as a link, but the text "Test" is not styled (appears as a standard web link).

(2)

HTML

```html
<div class="categoryName"><a href="#" onclick="toggle('category')">Test</a></div>
```

CSS is the same

In this case the text is styled but my box no longer acts as a link, just the text.

How can I have both my box acting as a link and the text styled?

Comment: You could give the particular anchor tag a class and do this `a.someclass {}`. But I dont think putting a div inside an anchor tag is valid HTML.

Comment: anchors are inline elements, divs are block elements, so yeah, it's not very good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is backwards

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('category')"><div class="categoryName">Test</div></a>
```

Here's how it should be:

```
 a .categoryName
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.categoryName a
```

is saying style `a` elements inside of the `.categoryName` element

This should work:

HTML

```
<a class="categoryName" href="#" onclick="toggle('category')"><div>Test</div></a>
```

CSS

```
.categoryName
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.categoryName div
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S9A7L/

So this is saying style the `div` element inside of the element with a class of `categoryName`.  I moved the class from the `a` to the `div` and changed the css.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve the same thing by simply doing this:

html

```
<a class="blocklink" href="#" onclick="toggle('category')">Test</a>
```

css

```
.blocklink {
    display:block; /* ! */
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

... no need for a div at all.